# openCPU and rstan - cannot open the connection

Tags: r, opencpu, stan, rstan

I'm using openCPU to create an API to estimate pretty basic models in rstan.

I have verified that my function works in my environment when called from a normal R console session, as opposed to called from openCPU.

But when called via openCPU, the response is the following:

```
cannot open the connection

In call:
file(con, "r")
```

By inserting checkpoints in the source of rstan, I've traced this to one call in R/cxxfunplus.R ([link to line on github here](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/blob/develop/rstan/rstan/R/cxxfunplus.R#L151)):

```
dso <- new('cxxdso', sig = sig, dso_saved = save_dso, 
             dso_filename = dso_filename, 
             modulename = module_name, 
             system = R.version$system, 
             cxxflags = get_makefile_flags("CXXFLAGS"), 
             .CXXDSOMISC = new.env(parent = emptyenv()))
```

What in this call is trying to read a connection that might fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out - one of the two makefiles that `rstan::get_makefile_txt` is looking for doesn't exist when run under openCPU. The file is /usr/share/R/share/make.

Fortunately the first makefile does exist and is sufficient, so this can be corrected by skipping the second makefile and only reading the first.

Before the last line of `rstan::get_makefile_text`, I inserted the following:

```
makefiles <- makefiles[file.exists(makefiles)]
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Can you add to your answer whatever it is you called to only read the first makefile?

Comment: OK. I added that line to the develop branch for rstan on GitHub.